# How can i split a spark df (large df) by rows into mutliple dfs in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

We have a split function in python `df_split = np.array_split(df,2)`, which splits the df by rows into multiple df. How can we achieve the same for a spark df?

Comment: Check if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62107654/efficiently-batching-spark-dataframes-to-call-an-api/62166913#62166913

Answer (score -1):

The simple way is to filter on some condition.

```
first_half = my_df.filter(condition)
second_half = mydf.filter(~condition)
```

You may need to add another field to your frame.  You did not say how you wanted it to be split.  If you want it split in half, such as every other row, then you can add a row number, and then the condition would be row number is even (using modulo or something.